# created < 2010-10-10 Using KQL on Sharepoint 2013

Tags: kql

```
 String queryText = "Created<2010-10-10 and IsDocument:1";

  KeywordQuery keywordQuery = new KeywordQuery(siteCollection);
  keywordQuery.RowLimit = 500;  
  keywordQuery.QueryText = querytext;
  keywordQuery.SelectProperties.Add("RecordOWSCHCS");
  keywordQuery.SelectProperties.Add("RetentionPeriodOWSCHCS");
  keywordQuery.SelectProperties.Add("Created");

  SearchExecutor searchExecutor = new SearchExecutor();
  ResultTableCollection resultTableCollection =  searchExecutor.ExecuteQuery(keywordQuery);

                var resultTables = resultTableCollection.Filter("TableType", KnownTableTypes.RelevantResults);
                var resultTable = resultTables.FirstOrDefault();
                System.Data.DataTable dataTable = resultTable.Table;
                return dataTable;
```

This program  returns  only 2010- Octoboer data(Month data) as search result. Even if there are 2010-August data and 2010-September data.

Comment: Have you tried testing this within SharePoint? You can create a result source and use the GUI to test your query.

Comment: Can I use query like this?                                                              ((IsDocument:1 and Created<=2010-11-04 and RecordOWSCHCS:yes and RetentionPeriodOWSCHCS:T) or (IsDocument:1 and Created<=2012-08-10 and RecordOWSCHCS:yes and RetentionPeriodOWSCHCS:N/A))

Comment: Problem is "Created date range". I got one  search result row as 2012 data with RecordOWSCHCS:yes and RetentionPeriodOWSCHCS:T which is wrong.   I can not use multiple conditions with KQL?

Comment: Try it in the GUI like I said.  And change it to something like this: `IsDocument:1 RecordOWSCHCS:yes ((RetentionPeriodOWSCHCS:N/A AND Created<=2012-08-10) OR RetentionPeriodOWSCHCS:T)`

Comment: When I run this query within a result source on sharepoint, I got 414 rows return. But, I got 319 rows after running the programming code. Still show wrong created row.

Comment: ((IsDocument:1 AND Created<=2009-11-10 AND RecordOWSCHCS:yes AND RetentionPeriodOWSCHCS:T) OR (IsDocument:1 AND Created<=2012-08-10 AND RecordOWSCHCS:yes AND RetentionPeriodOWSCHCS:N/A)) works fine. I just changed lower case with upper case . or-->OR  and-->AND.